# when user enters Indian rupee symbol (₹) or other currency symbols in react native android device they are sending to server as "â‚¹"

Tags: android, react-native, axios

when user types currency symbols like Indian rupee ₹ in android input field and click on submit then  value sent to server is "â‚¹" instead of ₹ in the request.

But when i print the console before making axios api request it is printing ₹ in the console correctly.

So iam thinking there might be some encoding need to be done while making axios request.

Please help me if anybody know how to send the special symbols in react native.

My sample code using fetch

```
 let data = {
      message: this.state.internalValue,
    };
    fetch('https://www.myapi.com', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(data)
    });
```

using axios

```
axios.post("https://www.myapi.com", data)
      .then(response => {
     
      })
      .catch(error => {
       
      });
```

using form data in axios

```
   let jsondata = {
      message: this.state.internalValue,
    };

    var axios = require('axios');
    var FormData = require('form-data');
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('data', true);

    var config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       
      },
    };

    axios.post('https://myapi.com',jsondata,config)
      .then((response) => {
     
      })
      .catch(error => {
    
      });
```

Current behavior

When i debug the request in android studio profiler the value is sending like this instead of ₹.

```
{
"message": "â‚¹"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like**
**For formdata**

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data", true);

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8;"
      }
    };

    axios.post(URL, formData, config).then(
      response => {
        console.log({ response });
      },
      error => {
        console.log({ error });
      }
    );
```

`For normal fetch`

```
fetch(uri, {
    headers:{
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }
  })
  .then(
  (response) => {
    var contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
    console.warn(contentType)
      return response.json()
    }
    ).then((myJson) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

Comment: I am getting Network  error when i try using axios.

Comment: Hi I tried like this.

1. using fetch

 let data = {
      message: this.state.internalValue,
    };
    fetch('https://www.myapi.com', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify(data)
    });

2. Using axios

axios.post("https://www.myapi.com", data)
      .then(response => {
     
      })
      .catch(error => {
       
      });